# Get damage value and school of magic incoming damage (WoW 1.13)

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

How do I get damage value and school of incoming damage magic using api World Of WarCraft 1.13 in lua language? Damage caused to me by another player or mob.
This is necessary so that I can use

```
print("You received " .. damageValue .. " " .. damageSchool .. " damage")
```

So that I can get in the chat:

> You received 100 Fire damage
>
> You received 50 Physical damage

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic combat log should be almost the same as retail
See https://wow.gamepedia.com/COMBAT_LOG_EVENT

```lua
local playerGUID = UnitGUID("player")
local MSG_PLAYER_DAMAGE = "You received %d %s damage"

local damageEvents = {
    SWING_DAMAGE = true,
    SPELL_DAMAGE = true,
}

local f = CreateFrame("Frame")
f:RegisterEvent("COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED")
f:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event)
    self:OnEvent(event, CombatLogGetCurrentEventInfo())
end)

function f:OnEvent(event, ...)
    local timestamp, subevent, _, sourceGUID, sourceName, sourceFlags, sourceRaidFlags, destGUID, destName, destFlags, destRaidFlags = ...
    local spellId, spellName, spellSchool
    local amount, overkill, school, resisted, blocked, absorbed, critical, glancing, crushing, isOffHand

    if subevent == "SWING_DAMAGE" then
        amount = select(12, ...)
    elseif subevent == "SPELL_DAMAGE" then
        spellId, spellName, spellSchool, amount = select(12, ...)
    end

    if damageEvents[subevent] and destGUID == playerGUID then
        print(MSG_PLAYER_DAMAGE:format(amount, GetSchoolString(spellSchool or 0x1)))
    end
end
```